# Is $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 |1\leq x^2 +y^2 <4\} $ an open set?

Tags: calculus

> Is $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |1\leq x^2 +y^2 <4\}$ an open set?

I found this to be a circle area centered in $(0,0)$ with radius less than $2$ and excluding another circle area radius  $1$.

No I know a set $A$ is called "open" if for every point $a\in A$  there is some open ball $B_r(a)$ contained in $A$ (i.e. there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(a) \subset A$.

I'm going to say it's not open. Because if I had an infinitely small ball with origin outside $x^2+y^2 = 1. There is no value I can minus from 1 small enough to keep it larger than 1.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but your reasoning doesn't justify it. Try taking a *specific* point $a=(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1,$ and show that there is no $r>0$ such that $B_r(a)\subseteq A.$

Comment: Exercise: If $A := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid 1 < x^{2} + y^{2} < 4 \}$, is $A$ open?

Comment: Yes because you can construct a ball that is infinitely small around points (0.999 and 3.99) and still have it within the parameter) 1<f(x)<4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point $(1,0)$ belongs to $A$, but no complete neighborhood is contained in $A$. Can you say why?

Comment: You cannot have a ball or circle with origin (1,0) that can have a  radius small enough such that $ x^2+y^2\ge 1 $